# Failing to understand the logic needed in a function I'm wanting to refactor

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Currently practicing my JavaScript and I'm struggling to get my head around the logic of a function I'm needing to adapt. the idea behind the program isto turn user inputs into JSON.

Currently my program can write the JSON as followed:

```js
  {
    "Name": "Jane",
    "Surname": "Doe"
  }
```

The "Surname : Doe" is inserted with the fucntion which I'm trying to refactor:

```js
addNewParent: function () {
      let infoBoxOne = this.$refs.inputKey.value;
      let infoBoxTwo = this.$refs.inputValue.value;

      //map over the array and set value equal to value
       const new_array = this.objects.map(x => x)

       const last = Object.keys(new_array)[Object.keys(new_array).length-1];
       console.log(last)

      const temp = this.objects.flatMap((obj, index) => {
        if (index === last.length - 1) {
        return { ...obj, [infoBoxOne]: infoBoxTwo };
        }
       return obj;
     });
        this.objects = temp;
     
      document.getElementById("inputKey").value = "";
      document.getElementById("inputValue").value = "";
 
    },
```

This currently works for any "parent" that doesn't follow a child:

```js
[
  {
    "Name": "Jane",
    "Surname": "Doe",
    "Age": "45",
    "gender": "female",
    "eyecolor": "blue",
    "haircolor": "red"
  }
]
```

However the issue arises when I add a child into the object, I'm now wanting to target that child object with the same function.

Currently the object targets the "main" object and sticks in a key:value. (as seen by the code snippet under "FROM".. I need it to find the last object - either child and insert key:value OR (on the main object if no child exists) and insert the key:value- shown by the code snippet under to: –

From:

```js
[
  {
    "Name": "Jane",
    "Surname": "Doe",
    "Age": "45",
    "gender": "female",
    "eyecolor": "blue",
    "haircolor": "red",
    "address": {
      "lineone": "17 Summer Hill vue"
    },
    "city": "Some city"
  }
]
```

to:

```js
[
  {
    "Name": "Jane",
    "Surname": "Doe",
    "Age": "45",
    "gender": "female",
    "eyecolor": "blue",
    "haircolor": "red",
    "address": {
      "lineone": "17 Summer Hill vue",
      "city": "Some city"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You shouldn't rely on any order in the properties of an object. When `new_array` is an array, then using `Object.keys(new_array)` to get to the last entry is strange. Just use indexing. But, I have no clue what you want to achieve here. Calling this JSON is also confusing. The term JSON should better be reserved for the text data exchange format. Here you have an array of plain objects.

Comment: Currently the object targets the overall object and sticks in a key:value. (as seen by the code snippet under "FROM"..

I need it to find the last object - either child and insert key:value  OR (on the main object if no child exists) and insert the key:value- shown by the code snippet under to:

Comment: With just two text input fields, one for the key and one for the value, you have no way of indicating where the key/value pair should be inserted in fact the current function always add or updates attributes at the "root" level (see `return { ...obj, [infoBoxOne]: infoBoxTwo }`). If you want to add the possibility of selecting where to add/update attributes, you need either check-boxes or radio buttons (depending on whether you want to allow adding/inserting attributes in different places simultaneously) that are updated every time a new child, grandchild or descendant is added to the parent.

Comment: ... and you obviously have to handle all the JavaScript part add/update attributes at the correct level

Comment: if I set up another function could I potentially target the last object found (in this case the child one and push the key/value into that?